# Connection for a 2 switch ceiling fan additional question

Tags: electrical

So I separate the 2 white wires and label the hot one black? How do I determine the hot white wire without a tester?

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Did you make a new user to post a follow-up to something else?  There's not enough detail or context here to answer your question.  Each question should stand on its own and not require details from other questions.

Comment: [Original question, BTW](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168812/connection-for-a-2-switch-ceiling-fan)

Comment: It sounds like you changed accounts, possibly because you are not associating your account with an email, and it's relying on a browser cookie to identify you. That doesn't work across browsers or devices, and if you reset your cookies your old account is gone. I recommend adding an email and then asking mods to merge your accounts.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.